# Detect when video has changed - YouTube iFrame API

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have some kind of slider with a YouTube playlist in the background. I'd like to know when the video has changed, so I can change the slider text to the right text.

I've searched the API page (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events) and can't seem to find an event that fires when the video changes. Is there one?

Here's my code until now.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

window.player;
var player;

var playlistVideos = new Array();
jQuery('#playlistSlider span').each(function(){
    playlistVideos.push(jQuery(this).html());
})

//console.log(playlistVideos)

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('playlistSlider', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        loadPlaylist:{
            listType:'playlist',
            list:playlistVideos,
            index:parseInt(0),
            //suggestedQuality:'small'
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            //'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        },
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.loadPlaylist(playlistVideos);
    event.target.mute();
    event.target.setLoop(true);
}
```

A bonus would also be to know what is the current video playing (index).

Comment: Hey, did my answer help?  Feel free to follow up with any other questions.

Comment: Have yet to try it, but sounds right.

Comment: Yup that worked. I made an object with my text assigned to every video ID in my playlist, and changed the text via the current video id each time the onplayerstatechange is fired (got the id from http://stackoverflow.com/a/14778040/954867)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen for the player's `onStateChange` callback.

```
events: {
    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
}
```

If the event value is 0, the video has ended

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == 0) {
        // video ended
    }
}
```

For knowing the index of the current playing video, keep a variable `index` which is initially set to 0.  As the current video ends and the next one loads, increment your `index` by one.  The `index` value will point to the current video in your `playlistVideos`.

Answer (score -1):

In the HTML, to create your list, do:

```
<div id="playlistSlider">
 <span>p-nx3VdC-ZY</span>
 <span>yR-KUXb5gFU</span>
</div>
```

To check if video is ended, use `event.data == -1`